# In a Java nested for-loop, the code works properly if separated into 2 different for-loops. If nested, the outer loop doesn't increment. Thoughts?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I'm having some trouble with a nested for loop. After days of agonizing searching and trial and error, I finally got the math working for a temperature conversion table. When I separate this code, it works great. Celsius converts to Fahrenheit and vise versa and both sides loop properly. However, when I try and nest the for loops, one side stops working. I've tried moving my statements around, but I keep coming up with the same result which is one side will not increment while the other side does. I'm new to Java so I don't see what I'm doing wrong as I used a for loop on a previous program with success. I'm not sure what to do with the: f1 = CF(c1); I've tried it in both loops while nested. ANY insight is greatly appreciated.

```
static double c1, f1; // c1 is the celsius temp, f1 is the equivalent 
                      // fahrenheit temp
static double f2, c2; // f2 is the fahrenheit temp, c2 is the equivalent 
                      //   celsius temp

double start = -50;
double finish = 50;
int five = 5;

for (c1 = start; c1 <= finish; c1 += five) {                

    f1 = CF(c1);

    for (f2 = start; f2 <= finish; f2 += five){
                
        c2 = FC(f2);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.format("%6.3fC %6.3fF <> %6.3fF %6.3fC", f2, c2, c1, f1);
    }
}
```

As stated above, when the for loops are separated, everything works properly. When the loops are nested, the outer loop stops working, while the inner loop functions properly. To clarify, the inner loop converts fahrenheit to celsius and prints them starting from -50 to 50 in increments of 5. However, this is a snippet of what I'm getting

```
30.000C     -1.111F <>   50.000F    122.000C
35.000C      1.667F <>   50.000F    122.000C
40.000C      4.444F <>   50.000F    122.000C
45.000C      7.222F <>   50.000F    122.000C
50.000C     10.000F <>   50.000F    122.000C

My expected outcome should be:
30.000C   -1.111F <> 30.000C     86.000F
35.000C    1.667F <> 35.000C     95.000F
40.000C    4.444F <> 40.000C    104.000F
45.000C    7.222F <> 45.000C    113.000F
50.000C    10.000F<> 50.000C    122.000F
```

Comment: What are `CF` and `FC`? Those aren't included in the code you posted.

Comment: This is just a guess from what you've posted above, but: perhaps one or both of the functions `CF` and `FC` are modifying one of the statics you've defined (c1, f1, f2, c2). I'd try to rework the functions so that the only inputs they use are parameters that are passed into the functions – don't refer to any globally accessible things (like the four static `double` values you've defined).

Comment: instead of two loops, you need a single loop (eventually with two variables **¹**) - nested loops means that you will get all combinations of both variables || **1** `for (c1=startC, f2=startF; c1<=finishC && f2<=finishF; c1+=stepC, f2+=stepF)`

Comment: Both loops are working correctly, but note that the value of `f1` in the outer loop only changes once every 10 cycles of the inner loop (Not every cycle like you want in your example).

Comment: BTW 50°C is not 10°F, it is 122°F (Good values to test: 0°C=32°F and 100°C=212°F)

Comment: You only need one for loop and one conversion, from Celsius to Fahrenheit.  You already have the temperatures in Celsius.  By the way, the conversion is F = C * 9 / 5 + 32

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you my friend! This was the solution. I played with it a tiny bit, plugged the numbers in and off it went! Thank you! Also just to comment on the other comment you had, the temp conversion was correct, I just had to switch around where I printed C and F. All fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @user16320675, I combined everything into a single for-loop and it is now working as expected! I didn't even know you could combine for-loop statements with the && operator. User's suggestion that answered my problem was:

```
for (c1=startC, f2=startF; c1<=finishC && f2<=finishF; c1+=stepC, f2+=stepF)
```

I just made a couple tiny changes and off it went! Thank you everyone for your help and time!